# problem on setting up ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just started learning ruby on rails with "Lynda Ruby on Rails 3 Essential Training".

I finished the installation, and created rails application by writing- "rails new app".
After that when I wrote - "rails server", that's what I saw:

```
C:\Users\Oded\sites\simple_cms>rails server
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.r
b:2:in `require': 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   - C:/Ruby192/lib/r
uby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so (LoadError
)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/my
sql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/my
sql2.rb:7:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/my
sql2.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:64:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:62:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:62:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:51:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:51:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler.rb:11
2:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Oded/sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (re
quired)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:28:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:27:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Can you please help me find the solution?

Happy holidays,

Oded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing some gems! try running `bundle install`... then all should work.

EDIT: make sure that your `Gemfile` contains the line

```
gem 'mysql'
```

before running `bundle install`. Bundler will get you set up for mysql, dependencies and all.

Comment: sorry, added a clarification about a Gemfile requirement. The other answer is correct in that you need to make sure you have mysql installed, as per this guide: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/installing.html

Comment: It won't install MySQL for him and some users have reported webrick issues with using the mysql gem without it locally installed.

Comment: and I installed my app like this:"rails new app -d mysql"

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to this website and follow the directions ...

http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/

or in short download the connector mentioned in the article from mysql or a mirror site

Run this command:

```
gem install mysql --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-dir=C:/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32
```

Make sure you have the correct path to the mysql connector folder that has no spaces!!

After that is complete make sure you copy the *`libmysql.dll`* file from the connector library you unzipped and downloaded and placed that in the Ruby\bin file.

After that delete the connector libary and start it up by typing 'rails server' making sure your gem file has the line `gem 'mysql'` or `gem 'mysql2'` I'm not sure which one so try both.  It sucks and they really need to fix this for windows.