# Rails project using MySQL gem not starting up on Windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

My specs are as follow:

- Windows 8 64-bit
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Rails 3.2.12

I installed rails via the [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/windows). I have also installed the mysql2 gem. I created a new project that is pre-configured to use mysql e.g.

> rails new project_name -d mysql

I then tried to start up the server/WEBrick via

> rails server

And I get the following error:

[image]

I've tried this using the mysql2 as well as teh mysql gem. Both times I get the same error. When I use the default sqlite then the project starts up fine and I can view it on *localhost:3000*.

I'm aware that mysql2 used to be a problem on rails, but since mysql isn't working either I'm of the opinion that it's a Windows 8 specific project, surprise surprise.

I'd deff like to use MySQL rather than SQLite. Thanks for anyone that can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a noted error case,

The [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493487/unable-to-start-the-rails-server) says-

`"The problem is with mysql. It is a 64 bit installation. Change it to 32bit and it runs fine."`

Apart from that, this error may also be the result of some missing gems.
You should try running `bundle install` before running your server.

Also make sure that `gem mysql` is added to your gemfile before you do `bundle install`.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Will accept the answer if that is indeed the case. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you mean adding gem 'mysql2' to your gemfile instead of gem 'mysql'?

Comment: No, its just `gem 'mysql'`. Check out that- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328632/problem-on-setting-up-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Installing the 32bit version worked! That is using the mysql2 gem as well. Thanks Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

Please update your MySQL to 64bit version. It will fix the problem. Don't forgot to install the `Devkit`.

Comment: Installation WAS a 64bit. Which didn't work. Installing the 32bit version of Mysql worked.